# How can I can I get scrollTo to work correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a multiple select list defined like this

```
<select id="MyId" multiple="multiple">
    <option value = 1>This is one</option>
     etc...
</select>
```

I am trying to use the scrollTo plugin like this

```
$("#MyId option").scrollTo("[value=1]", 100)
```

I have tried a few different combinations with no results.

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Edit: I want to be able to scroll to any given value. Not just 1

Comment: ??? It might be my lack of intelligence, but I absolutely can't follow, what you try to do.

Comment: What functionality you want to achieve ? `scrollTo` seems to be out dated.

Comment: @SvenBieder, I have a knack for that sorry.

Comment: @jams. I have a large multiselect list that I am trying to scroll to a specific value when it is selected using jQuery at a different time. It will be visual feedback in essence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.scrollTop, nor.position() returned a pixel value (they returned 0). So instead I used .index() on the value I was searching for in my option elements. I then multiplied it by the height of one element in the select lis. Ithen used scrollTop(), passing in the value found previous

Answer (score 1):

You should use `scrollTop()` of jQuery

```
$("#MyId option").scrollTop(100);
```

[Here you can read about it.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_scrolltop.asp) and [try it.](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_scrolltop_get)

Comment: @tympaniplayer: You should read links given in my answer first.

Comment: I am not sure how to get the scrollTop of a particular value in my select list. For example I would expect to get a value that is not 0 if I am halfway scrolled through my list and my value is at the top. Using     $("#MyId [value=1]").scrollTop();

Comment: @tympaniplayer: `scrollTop()` method takes int value to scroll. You can use `position() ` method to get top. Here you can read http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/css_position.asp

Comment: For some reason position is still returning top and left of 0 for an element that is halfway through the list. I can find it using the .find() jquery method. Thanks for your help though